# Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Program.Max(int[])" требуется ссылка на объект

Tags: c#

Прошу не судить строго, я начинающий. Не могу никак разобраться в причине. 
Заранее благодарю за помощь

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp27
{
    class Program
    {

        public int Max(int[] array)
        {
            int max = array[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (max < array[i])
                {
                    array[i] = max;
                }

            }
            return max;
        }



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] CatsAges = new int[] {2, 3, 1, 8, 9};

            Max(CatsAges);


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int Max(int[] array) // <- static
{
  ...
```